# Bootstrap menus not working on github page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, github-pages

Below are my problems:

1. Not sure whether preloader is working or not due to Preloader and
   dom elements are loading at the same time.
2. In local environment, menu links are working but menus are not working in
   GitHub page. Please check the style button. If I do `right-click` on it and
   choose "open link in new tab" it loads the page in a new tab but if
   I simply click it is not working?

Demo: http://rushdi1987.github.io/myfolio/

Answer (score 0):

Please check console errors and network tab of browser

```
GET 
http://rushdi1987.github.io/myfolio/css/waypoints.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 38ms]
GET 
http://rushdi1987.github.io/myfolio/css/owl.carousel.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 34ms]
GET 
http://rushdi1987.github.io/myfolio/css/owl.theme.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 38ms]
GET 
http://rushdi1987.github.io/myfolio/js/owl.carousel.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 15ms]

TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function
```

Your resources plus jquery is not available.

Best would be to load javascript using [defer](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html) attribute so that it loads after `content` is loaded